# Programmatically getting executable SQL from a LINQ query at run-time

Tags: c#, sql, linq, runtime

I know about [Scott Gu's LINQ to SQL visualiser](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx), but is there a way to take a LINQ expression at run-time and do something to find out the **full** resulting SQL?

Comment: Isn't this *exactly* what LINQ to SQL visualizer does? Clarifying the difference might be better.

Comment: Hmmm I thought I put "Programmatically" in the title but I obviously didn't. I've added it now.

Comment: @mehrdad: Josh might want to get the SQL statement in code and log it to e.g. an error log or something. The interactive visualizer isn't much help for that :-)

Comment: Note that the source code to the visualizer is available which might allow you to adapt it to a class library to use the features you need programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Log feature on the DataContext and write your own code to evaluate the sql.  An example here on [logging SQL to the debug window](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kris/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11) should get you started on pulling out the SQL.

Comment: Hmmm I shall investigate this tomorrow, if it works I'll be a happy SO ticker!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourProvider.GetCommand(yourQuery).CommandText;
```

Comment: darn - you beat me by a few seconds :-)

Comment: almost, but no - it's not a query I can run; it's parameterised without the actual values in there like the LINQ to SQL Visualiser provides

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ2SQL you can just call `.ToString()` from the composed query.